# Deploying multiple versions of Angular app to Azure App Service using Application Type option not working

Tags: angular-router, url-rewrite-module, azure-appservice, angular12

I have an angular application deployed in Azure App Service. There are two versions of the app : v1 and v2.

v1 URL: https://myapp.com/v1

v2 URL: https://myapp.com

1. v1 version : Deployed under the Virtual path : /v1 and with Type: Application
2. v2 version: Deployed in the root : / and with Type: Application

By default whenever user is navigating to the url : https://myapp.com should load the v2 version pointing to the root and serve the application. Both the apps have modules : Module 1 and Module 2.

If someone clicks on Module 1 of v2 app then it should open the Module 1 of v2 app. But in case someone clicks on Module 2 with v2 app then it should redirect to Module 1 of v1 app in this case.
[image]

Can you please help me to fix this issue